# List `yum/dnf` history in ascending (reversed) order

Tags: command-line, package-management, yum, dnf

When you run `yum history` (or `dnf history`) it will give you the list of action starting from the last, most recent action being on top of the list. In case you have a lot of history steps your recent action happens to be on top of the list and you need to do a lot of scrolling to get to it.

Is there a way to list `yum/dnf` history in ascending order, so the latest step would be at the bottom of the results?

Comment: you can pipe the output into `tac`.

Comment: Like @meuh mentioned and like with any other linux command, you can pipe the output to `tac` which is a reversed `cat` to get your sort order. yum itself doesn't offer such an option, compare e.g. https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Yum-Transaction_History.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as mentioned in the comments, `tac` command does what was asked.

Simply run:

```
dnf history | tac
```